# Update MongoDB objects using existing objects

Tags: mongodb, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert my mongodb data into more simpler format, but I don't know how to check if certain field is an array and update those only.

I have this kind of objects in my database currently

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"), "name" : "Yeti ", "channel" : "ABC", "showed" : { "_isAMomentObject" : true, "_i" : "25.3.2014 23:40", ... }}
```

I also has some rows which are in new format already:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"), "name" : "Yeti ", "channel" : "ABC", "showed" : "25.3.2014 23:40" }
```

I would like to update all my objects which has array type in "showed" property into an object which has showed._i in showed property.

showed._i => showed, for all objects which have array in showed property.

I tried to do this update using my backup collection, but it put null into showed property for all objects:

```
db.programs_bak.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { db.programs.update( { _id: doc._id }, { showed: doc.showed._i },{ }); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.programs_bak.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
       db.programs.update( { _id: doc._id },
                           {$set : { "showed" : doc.showed._i}});
                        });
```

Comment: Care to explain the code you have slapped down or *why*/*how* it should be used

Comment: It seems that i have missed $set. It still makes me wonder why the value is nulled if im not "setting" anything :).

Comment: Old data is now converted, bad thing is that new rows which were inserted in last two weeks have now a null in showed because they didnt have _i property. I have to figure those out.